# Django decorator @transaction.non_atomic_requests not working in a ViewSet method

Tags: python, django, transactions, django-rest-framework

I recently ran into the need to disable transaction requests in one of my views, in order to be able to call `db.connection.close()` and `connect()` during requests in an effort to improve performance.

I have a DRF ViewSet, and used the following very simple view to verify that the non_atomic_requests decoractor seems to have no effect. `ATOMIC_REQUESTS=True` is enabled in `settings.py`, and `DEBUG=False`.

```
from django.db import transaction    

@transaction.non_atomic_requests
def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
    m = MyModel(stuff="hello")
    m.save()
    raise Exception('exception! row should still be saved though')
    return Response()
```

After calling the view, I open Django shell, and verify that the amount of rows in the db has not grown, even though it should have. Also opening a debugger during the request to halt execution after the line `m.save()`, I can observe in Django shell that a new row is not visible yet.

If I set `ATOMIC_REQUESTS=False` in `settings.py`, the code works as expected, and the number of rows in the db is grown by one, even if an error is raised before returning from the view.

When `ATOMIC_REQUESTS=False`, using `@transaction.atomic` decorator does work as expected though. So as a workaround, I could use it to set every other view as atomic instead...

I am currently thinking this is a bug in the framework. Can anybody verify my findings, or point out if I am misunderstanding how this decorator is meant to function?

I am using Python 3.6, Django 2.0 and DRF 3.7.7.

Comment: The return line is never reached because of the previous raise

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[As documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.non_atomic_requests), `non_atomic_requests` only works if it's applied to the view itself.

In your case, `create` is a viewset method, it is not the view itself. With a regular class based view in Django, you'd need to wrap the `dispatch` method using [`method_decorator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class).

```
@method_decorator(transaction.non_atomic_requests, name='dispatch') 
class MyViewSet(ViewSet):
    ...

    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

I'm not familiar enough with the rest framework internals to say whether this will work or not. Note that it will disable atomic requests for *all* views handled by the viewset, not just the `create` method.

The `non_atomic_requests` method has this limitation because the Django request handler has to inspect the view before it runs so that it knows whether to run it in a transaction. The `transaction.atomic` decorator does not have the same requirement - Django can simply start the transaction as soon as it enters an atomic function or block.

Comment: Has anyone confirmed that this works with Django Rest Framework ViewSets? It has not worked for me.

Comment: @JoshuaSwain it looks to me as if it should work, because the viewset copies attributes from the dispatch method [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/580bf45ccfd5c423a938729907d813f4862dca38/rest_framework/viewsets.py#L132). I haven’t tried it to confirm that it does work.

Comment: @JoshuaSwain it's working for me.

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

@method_decorator(transaction.non_atomic_requests, name="dispatch")
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def create(self, request):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using db other than 'default':
you need to explicitly mention the 'using' property.
otherwise, it would default to 'default'

```py
transaction.non_atomic_requests(using='db_name')
```

in case of class based views-
either apply it on dispatch in views:

```py
@method_decorator(transaction.non_atomic_requests(using='db_name'), name='dispatch') 
class MyViewSet(ViewSet):
...
```

or apply it on as_view method in urls

```py
path(r'endpoint/', transaction.non_atomic_requests(using='db_name')(MyViewSet.as_view()), name='myview')
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Django REST Framework ViewSets, you have to consider that the *actual* Django route will be the result of calling `.as_view({})` on the ViewSet.

Thus, you'd need to decorate the .dispatch() method of the resulting Class-based view. Given that `rest_framework.viewsets.ViewSet > rest_framework.views.APIView > django.views.generic.base.View`, and that the Django documentation explicitly mentions the `View.dispatch()` method, you should know you can either use `@method_decorator` over the ViewSet.

In an implementation I'm working on, we found out that decorating the dispatch method works as well:

```
class MyView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        return Response("Hello!")

    @transaction.non_atomic_requests()
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Beware that this will make requests for all methods to be decorated, and you will have to handle transactions manually in all of them.